# bootstrap popover not working due to file conflict due to add or remove of files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap popover on my page.

I have following code

```
$("#s1").popover({ placement: 'top' }).popover("show");
```

I have added following files to my page

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map">vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map</a>
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map">vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map</a>
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It was working fine some time ago. But I am not sure maybe some files I added or removed but now it's not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried ripping all of that out and adding them one by one to see what works/doesnt work?

Comment: yes I have checked that

Comment: also, is there a reason to have both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css? (same with bootstrap-theme.css/bootstrap-theme.min.css, jquery-1.4.1.js, jquery-ui.js, bootraps.js, etc.)

Comment: why do you use full script and script min. Please remove one of them.

Comment: In addition to removing the double scripts, it may depend on which version of bootstrap you're using. E.g. bootstrap v3.1.1 depends on at least jquery version 1.9, and you're using a rather old jquery version.

Comment: You are loading jQuery twice and v1.4.1 is ancient and not supported by bootstrap.js. You need to use at least v 1.11.1

Comment: @Macsupport It worked. U are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice and v1.4.1 is ancient and not supported by bootstrap.js. You need to use at least v 1.11.1